# Erro Laravel. Problema ao inserir registro no banco de dados usando create($request->all())

Tags: laravel, controller

Eu estou sentando inserir registro no banco de dados pelo Controller:

```
 public function store(ServiceRequest $request,$id)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $data["organ_id"] = $id;
        $data["value"] = Valor($request->value);
        $service = Service::create($data);
        $service->local()->sync($request->local_id);
        return redirect()->route('admin.organ.service-show',$id)->withToastSuccess('Serviço adicionado!');
    }
```

Mas aparece o erro: Array to string conversion.
Mas se eu usar:

```
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $data["organ_id"] = $id;
        $data["value"] = Valor($request->value);
        $data["name"] = $request->name;
        $data["description"] = $request->description;
        $data["who"] = $request->who;
        $data["docs"] = $request->docs;
        $data["old_info"] = $request->old_info;
        $data["link"] = $request->link;
        $data["channel_services"] = $request->channel_services;
        $data["channel_communication"] = $request->channel_communication;
        $data["channel_manifest"] = $request->channel_manifest;
        $data["commitment_service"] = $request->commitment_service;
        $data["legislation"] = $request->legislation;
        $data["sector"] = $request->sector;
        $data["responsible"] = $request->responsible;
        $data["deadline"] = $request->deadline;

        $service = Service::create($data);
        $service->local()->sync($request->local_id);
        return redirect()->route('admin.organ.service-show',$id)->withToastSuccess('Serviço adicionado!');
    }
```

Ele insere perfeitamente. O que pode ser?

Comment: Não utilize $request->all(), utilize a validação do Laravel (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validation-quickstart) e depois $request->validated()

Answer (score 0):

Vi que muitos enfrentam esse problema aparentemente com o Laravel 8, então testei várias formas, e achei a solução: ele não está aceitando campos com '_' ou seja, 'local_id[]', então mudei para 'local[]' e deu certo. Grande abraço.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).